# ADF : How to pass additional information for each attribute from AM to UI

Tags: oracle-adf

Jdeveloper Version: 12.1.3(Build JDEVADF_12.1.3.0.0_GENERIC_140521.1008.S).

We have use case where I need to pass additional information for each VO attribute from AMImpl to UI(jspx/jsff)
For example,
EmployeeVO
  -FirsName
  -LastName
  -Email
  -PhoneNumber

While rendering in UI, for each of these attributes, I need to pass status information(which is not persisted in database. Its calculated information based on some functionality)

Is there a way to pass this additional information from AMImpl to UI?

Thanks in advance.
Rakesh Patsalla

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this outside of AM is to create a ViewRowImpl for each view object you wish to pass additional information as well as transient attributes in the views to contain the status information. On the getter for each attribute (FirstName, LastName, etc.) in the ViewRowImpl, you can obtain both database values that are in other attributes in the View for the current row, as well as call methods to obtain calculated values for that row. You would store calculated values in the transient attributes by calling their setters from within the getters of the target attributes doing the method calls. You then add the transient attributes to your UI. For example, in the ViewRowImpl:

```
public String getFirstName {
  String tmpFirstName = (String)getAttributeInternal(FIRSTNAME);
  String calculatedVal1 = myMethod(tmpFirstName);
  setTransientAttribute1(calculatedVal1);
  return (String)getAttributeInternal(FIRSTNAME);
}
```